# symlink to mounted windows folder not working

Tags: windows, centos, symlink

I've researched a lot and nothing I've tried seems to work the way I want it to. Maybe I'm not fully understanding how this is supposed to work but I created a folder on a windows share... then i went into my centOS 6.5 box, created a dir under /mnt/WinShare, edited my fstab with //servername/sharename/foldername /mnt/WinShare cifs credentials=/home/backup/.csfs 0 0, rebooted the box and confirmed the folder mounts automatically.

we have a program I'm testing out for our environment which dumps some output into a folder /home/programname/data/. I'm trying to link the contents of this folder to my windows mount so that the files actually go into my windows mount point and can be backed up on windows.

I've tried running ln -s /home/programname/data /mnt/WinShare but i get a "operation not supported" error message. Dug around and saw some posts saying i should be running it the opposite way so i changed it to ln -s /mnt/WinShare /home/programname/data which creates the symlink it doesn't do what I need. I thought symlinks were supposed to function like shortcuts? I kind of figured if i linked the two locations, whatever is in /home/programname/data should technically appear under /mnt/WinShare?

I found a different method which involved making my linux box into a samba server then mounting to the linux smb share via network mapping in windows and then creating a symlink from that to the folder in my windows share....this seemed to work but seems like an overly complicated method. All I want to be able to do is link whatever linux folder I need to a mounted windows share/folder so the contents on the linux side appears on my windows server...

Comment: I guess a better way to ask this would be, is it possible to symlink (from centOS side) to a mount point? I dug around some more and I'm getting the impression that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's interested, this is basically a misunderstanding on my part. I know you can't symlink to an existing folder/directory but I kept thinking about the problem all wrong.

The solution was to delete the directory under /home/programname/data and then create the symlink by running ln -s /mnt/WinShare /home/programname/data. I was confused because the /home/programname/data directory is hard coded into the app and I thought removing the directory would make the app unusable.